# What does complexification mean for our particles in physics?

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory, representation-theory, complex-numbers, beyond-the-standard-model

As gauge group let's consider the [popular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO%2810%29_%28physics%29) $SO(10)$ group.

The fundamental representation $\pi$ of the corresponding Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(10)$ is $10$ dimensional

$$ \pi: \mathfrak{so}(10) \rightarrow  \Bbb R^{10}.$$

This is a real representation, because $\Bbb R^{10}$ is a real vector space.

In such theories in physics when we say particles are in the $10$ dimensional representation, we mean our particles, for example the Higgs fields, are $\in \Bbb R^{10}$. Thus we have $10$ real particles here. A convenient way to label these $10$ states is by using the eigenvalues of the Cartan generators.
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \{1,0,0,0,0\} \\
 \{-1,1,0,0,0\} \\
 \{0,-1,1,0,0\} \\
 \{0,0,-1,1,1\} \\
 \{0,0,0,-1,1\} \\
 \{0,0,0,1,-1\} \\
 \{0,0,1,-1,-1\} \\
 \{0,1,-1,0,0\} \\
 \{1,-1,0,0,0\} \\
 \{-1,0,0,0,0\} \\
\end{array}
\right). $$

This is known as the weight system of the $10$-dimensional representation.

This can be interpreted that we have $5$ particles and their $5$ corresponding antiparticles in this representation. For example,

$$\phi_1 \hat= \{1,0,0,0,0\} \leftrightarrow  \phi_1^c \hat=  \{-1,0,0,0,0\} .$$

Now a popular trick, because with a real $10$ one gets very wrong mass relations, is to complexify the $10$. This means we then look at

$$ \pi: \mathfrak{so}(10) \rightarrow  \Bbb C^{10}$$

*Our weight system does not change, because the weight system of a real representation is **defined** as the weight system of the corresponding complex representation. This definition is necessary, because only for complex representation the existence of the eigenvalues is given.*

Now our particles are $\in \Bbb  C^{10}$. If we view $ \Bbb C^{10}$ as a vector space over $ \Bbb C$, [we have the same $10$ basis vectors as for](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123448/what-is-the-standard-basis-for-fields-of-complex-numbers) $ \Bbb R^{10}$, but now complex linear combinations are allowed.

Instead, we can view $ \Bbb C^{10}$ as a vector space over $ \Bbb R$. Then we have 20 basis vectors. These are our physical $20$ degrees of freedom for a complex 10.

**My problem is interpreting these degrees of freedom in terms of particles and antiparticles.**

In addition to the $10$ basis vectors that we had for a real $10$, for example

$$ \phi_1 \hat= \{1,0,0,0,0\} \hat = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0 \\0\\\vdots \end{pmatrix} \quad , \quad \phi_2 \hat= \{-1,1,0,0,0\} \hat = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1 \\0 \\\vdots \end{pmatrix}$$

we have the basis vectors
$$ ?\hat= ? \hat = \begin{pmatrix} i \\0 \\0\\\vdots \end{pmatrix} \quad , \quad ? \hat= ? \hat = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\i \\0 \\\vdots \end{pmatrix}$$

**What are the weights and particles that correspond to these basis vectors?**

***In addition: which of these 20 degrees of freedom are now particle and antiparticle pairs, because the identification from above, I think, no longer holds?***

Comment: 10 real scalars are in the fundamental of $\mathfrak{so}(10)$ while 10 complex scalars are in the fundamental of $\mathfrak{so}(10) \oplus \mathfrak{u}(1)$.